# MariaDB ubuntu 20.04 letsencrypt set up ssl

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm having a bit of a problem with setting up SSL for mariaDB on my ubuntu 20.04.
I installed certbot generated a certificate and added the following lines to /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.conf:

```
ssl-ca=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem
```

When I do systemctl restart mariadb I get the error message:
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

When I look at /var/log/mysql/error.log I see:

```
2023-01-20 19:23:44 0 [ERROR] Failed to setup SSL
2023-01-20 19:23:44 0 [ERROR] SSL error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed
2023-01-20 19:23:44 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I'm a bit lost what to do!

I validated the urls to the certificates there are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the server error message isn't very descriptive. If loading of ca file or ca-path didn't succeed a general error `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed` will be returned.

You should get a more descriptive error message (e.g. file not found or permission denied) if you pass the root authority to the command line client which uses TLS implementation of Connector/C.

```
mariadb --ssl-ca=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem
```

The command line client must be executed under the same user under which the server starts (likely user `mysql`).